# Using appendTo to move filters on their correct position for either mobile or desktop version

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my current on-going website project, according to screen dimsensions the site is repsonsive, and among others, the filters list also moves to the either a mobile sidebar or in the body for the desktop version.

Considering the 'weight' of the filters data (there can be thousands), I currently create the filters once (currently in the desktop space) and then append them accordingly depending on screen resize using appendTo() to their correct place, either desktop filter position or mobile.

The thing is, that in either of the two following cases the filters have to be appended and I am worrying about performance:

a) filters are created on mobile side and are appendedTo desktop filter position if screen is larger than a specific resolution.
b) filters are created on desktop filter position and then appendedTo mobile side if screen is smaller than a specific resolution.

Is there a way so that the filters are BUILT on their correct place depending on screen resolution. Using two different versions of the website -desktop/mobile- are out of the question.

edit: Adding simple code.

html:

```
<div id="desktopwrap">
  <div id="filters">
  filters here
  </div
</div>

<div id="mobilewrap">

</div>
```

For screen detection I created a jquery function:

```
var deskdevc=null;

detectres = function() {
 pixelratio = window.devicePixelRatio;
 winwidth= screen.width / pixelratio;
 winheight= screen.height / pixelratio;
if ((winwidth > 960) || (winheight > 960)) {
  deskdevc=true;
};


var ffpos = function() { 
if (deskdevc) {
 if ($(window).width() > 960) {
$('#filters').appendTo('#desktopwrap');
} else {
$('#filters').appendTo('#mobilewrap');
}
};
};
};
    $(window).load(detectres);
```

Comment: you may want to include some relevant code you tried with, also how are you checking for screen resolution (can do via css or js for example)...?

Comment: From the edit, you seems to be able to get the device size also.. now, what is the problem..?

Comment: because I want to avoid every single appendTo()

Comment: ...for perfromance reasons that is..